# Nunit test project net45 using Costura.Fody success in Release and fail in Debug with exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.5, fody-costura

**Environment:**

vs 2017.9 /net45

using Costura.Fody v3.3.3

In Nunit test project
I run the command:

```
    dotnet test -f net45 -c Debug        //test fail
    dotnet test -f net45 -c Release      //test success
```

I get the error

> OneTimeSetUp: System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for '' threw an exception.
>     ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I added the file `FodyWeavers.xml` in the root of the test project as described in [Fody.Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura)

which contain:

```
    <Weavers>
        <Costura ExcludeAssemblies='myprogram.exe'
                 CreateTemporaryAssemblies='true'
                 DisableCleanup='true'
                 />
    </Weavers>
```

How to resolve the error in Debug?